# JavaScript. validar varios input en una sola función

Tags: javascript

el objetivo es que permita enviar el formulario solo si las cantidades son mayor a 12 (una docena); es para un sistema de ventas por mayor. funciona solo con la primera fila, las demás filas ya no obedece, gracias de antemano.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("formulario").addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario); 
});

function validarFormulario(evento) {
  evento.preventDefault();
    let cant_vm=  parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant_vm").value);
    let cant_actual=  parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant_actual").value);
      if (cant_actual<cant_vm){
         alert("Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a "+ cant_vm)
         document.formulario.cant_actual.focus()
         return 0; 
        }

  this.submit();
```

```html
<form action="echo.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Codigo</td>
        <td>Producto</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
        <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="T000010"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="TECLADO"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="" value="1" id="cant_actual"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="50"></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="T000011"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="MOUSE"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="" value="1" id="cant_actual"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="40"></td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="T000012"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="PARLANTE"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="" value="1" id="cant_actual"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="40"></td>
        <tr>
        </tbody>

</table>
<br>
 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
<br>
<label>Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a </label>
<input type="number" value="12" id="cant_vm">
```

el objetivo es que permita enviar el formulario solo si las cantidades son mayor a 12 (una docena); es para un sistema de ventas por mayor. funciona solo con la primera fila, las demás filas ya no obedece, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los `id` en HTML deberían ser únicos... tienes 3 que se llaman `cant_actual`, por eso cuando vas a buscar el elemento, te devuelve el primero (y por esa misma razon solo funciona con ese)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia entre una ID y una clase es que una ID solo se usa para identificar un solo elemento en nuestro HTML. Los ID solo se usan cuando un elemento de la página debe tener un estilo particular aplicado. Sin embargo, una clase puede usarse para identificar más de un elemento HTML.

En el mismo caso se aplica con Javascript, asi que lo que he hecho ha sido reemplazar todos los atributos `id="cant_actual"` con `class="cant_actual"` para poder obtenerlos con la funcion `document.getElementsByClassName` que devuelve un `array` con todos los elementos.

Luego solo queda recorrer ese bucle y hacer la misma comparativa que tenías hecha.

**Te adjunto la solución:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("formulario").addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario); 
});

function validarFormulario(evento) {
    evento.preventDefault();
    let cant_vm = parseFloat( document.getElementById("cant_vm").value );
    let cant_actual = document.getElementsByClassName("cant_actual");

    for(var i = 0; i < cant_actual.length; i++) {
      if (parseFloat(cant_actual[i].value) < cant_vm) {
         alert("Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a "+ cant_vm)
         cant_actual[i].focus()
         return 0; 
      }
    }  
}
```

```html
<form action="echo.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Codigo</td>
        <td>Producto</td>
        <td>Cantidad</td>
        <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="T000010"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="TECLADO"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="" value="1" class="cant_actual"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="T000011"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="MOUSE"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="" value="1" class="cant_actual"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="40"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="T000012"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="PARLANTE"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="" value="1" class="cant_actual"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="" value="40"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

</table>
<br>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Entrar">
</form>
<br>
<label>Solo se vende en cantidad, mayor a </label>
<input type="number" value="12" id="cant_vm">
```

Comment: Ambos tengan cuidado con el cierre de las etiquetas `</tr>`, no lo están haciendo.

Comment: muchas gracias c5vargas, muy clara tu explicación. Gracias

Comment: Tienes razón @DjCrazy no me había dado cuenta. Ya lo he modificado 